Search photos on Google Photo according to tags set on Samsung Gallery
I'm using Samsung A53, Android 14, One UI 6.1. I took a picture with the Samsung Camera app and I have added the tag #aaabbb to the photo with the help of the Samsung Gallery application. I did search for #aaabbb in Samsung Gallery and it works.
Now I need to search according to the tag in photos.google.com, but it does not work. The photo is uploaded to the server. I tried to enter both #aaabbb and aaabbb in the search input, but it did not find the required photo.

Thanks for adding the device model. I have checked on my Samsung device, and looks like this tagging is a Samsung feature, and the tags are stored inside Samsung's Gallery app data instead of being embedded in the photo file, so I'm afraid what you want is just impossible.
